# SonarQube API Resources - deprecated

Tags: sonarqube5.3

I've noticed the Resources have been deprecated in 5.4.  We make heavy use of this api and could not find a replacement.

How is the functionality of this API being replaced?

Answer (score 0):

To fetch projects, `/api/components/search_projects` can be used. Sample usage https://sonarqube.com/api/components/search_projects.

To get the list of all apis, you can use `api/webservices/list`.